# Criar botão com ícone ao lado

Tags: css

Estou tentando criar um botão com ícone ao lado, estou usando ícones do framework bootstrap, estou quebrando a cabeça para faze-lo, sei que o bootstrap tem um componente que faz isso, porém fica em outro estilo, gostaria de fazer personalizado

EX:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer criar o botão personalizado, ou utilizar ícones personalizados?

Comment: Botão com ícones já criados.

Comment: Interessante é que a tag button foi desenvolvida para atingir este tipo de necessidade mesmo. [Aqui](http://web.archive.org/web/20110721191046/http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/) tem um site que fala sobre as vantagens de se utilizar button, e não input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pela minha experiência com Bootstrap, o melhor caminho a seguir tende a ser o uso das classes já disponibilizadas pela framework, com formatação adicional para chegar ao que pretendemos.

## Formatação do Bootstrap

```html
<a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="icon">F</span> compartilhar
</a>
```

[image: Botão com formatação existente na framework Bootstrap]

## Formatação adicional

Criamos uma *class* para subscrever os estilos da framework que nos interessam alterar, neste exemplo a `btn-facebook`:

```html
<a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary btn-facebook">
    <span class="icon">F</span> compartilhar
</a>
```

```css
.btn-facebook{
    border-radius:0;
    background-color:#0971E4;
    padding-left:0;
    border:0 none;
}
.btn-facebook > span{
    padding:6px 12px;
    margin-right:12px;
    background-color:#0A62C4;
}
.btn-facebook:hover,
.btn-facebook:active,
.btn-facebook:focus{
    background:#0969d6;
}
.btn-facebook:hover > span,
.btn-facebook:active > span,
.btn-facebook:focus > span{
    background:#095bb8;
}
```

[image: Botão da framework bootstrap com alteração do pretendido]

## Formatação do Icon

Dado que a framework Bootstrap [vem com os *icons* da Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) e os que são disponibilizados não incluem *icons* de redes sociais, podemos adicionalmente fazer uso dos *icons* da Font Awesome que [contém inúmeras redes sociais](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#brand):

```html
<a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary btn-facebook">
    <span><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></span> compartilhar
</a>
```

Para o efeito, a forma mais rápida de o fazer é trocar o texto `f` pelo icon pretendido quer numa tag `<span/>` quer numa tag `<i/>` como sugerido no site da Font Awesome.

[image: Botão da framework bootstrap com alteração do pretendido e icon da Font Awesome]

---

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/tnnyabns/).

```css
/* A notação de importante (!important) só está em uso por causa da forma como o StackFiddle gera o output onde este CSS vem primeiro que as bibliotecas externas o que faz com que estes estilos percam prioridade. Ver exemplo no JSFiddle. */

.btn-facebook {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  background-color: #0971E4 !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  border: 0 none !important;
}
.btn-facebook > span {
  padding: 6px 12px !important;
  margin-right: 12px !important;
  background-color: #0A62C4 !important;
}
.btn-facebook:hover,
.btn-facebook:active,
.btn-facebook:focus {
  background: #0862c9 !important;
}
.btn-facebook:hover > span,
.btn-facebook:active > span,
.btn-facebook:focus > span {
  background: #0954ab !important;
}
p {
  padding: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>
  Botão com a formatação existente na framework:
  <br/>
  <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="icon">F</span> compartilhar
  </a>
</p>
<p>
  Botão com a classe que o altera para o estilo pretendido:
  <br/>
  <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary btn-facebook">
    <span class="icon">F</span> compartilhar
  </a>
</p>
<p>
  Botão com a classe que o altera para o estilo pretendido e com icons da Font Awesome:
  <br/>
  <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary btn-facebook">
    <span><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></span>compartilhar
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: +1 O resultado final ficou excelente! congrats!

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: O pessoal mandou bem nas respostas. Todas merecem +1.

Answer (score 10):

Com base na imagem de modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 32px;       /* altura c/ base na imagem do AP */
    position: relative;
    width: 140px        /* largura c/ base na imagem do AP*/
}

button span {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 32px !important; /*obs: sobrepondo a regra de line-height do 'font-awesome'*/
    top:0; bottom: 0
}

button .icon {
    background: #0A62C4;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    left: 0; width: 40px
}

button .title {
    background: #0971E4;
    right: 0; width: 100px
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>
<!-- ícone usado: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/facebook/ -->

<button>
    <span class='icon fa fa-facebook'></span>
    <span class='title'>Compartilhar</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

Versão apenas com o elemento `<button>`:

```css
.facebook {
  background: #0870E3;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 40px; /* 40px = tamanho :before + 10px */
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.facebook:before {
  content: 'f';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0A62C4;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<button class="facebook">Compartilhar</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se é bem isso isso que você quer, mas acredito que a partir disso você consiga chegar ao resultado que você deseja:

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn">
 <i class="fa fa-taxi align-top bigger-125"></i>
      Default
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-taxi align-top bigger-125"></i> Large button</button>
```